# Календарь jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Помогите пожалуйста решить следующую задачу.

1. Есть ссылка `<a href="#">Сегодня</a>`
   "Сегодня" - должно соответствовать текущей дате.
2. По клику на ссылке, должен появляться календарь для выбора даты. После выбора даты, календарь должен скрыться.
3. Слово "Сегодня", в ссылке, должно заменяться на выбранную дату.

Пробовал `datapicker`, но он работает только с `input`, а нужно, чтобы дата заменяла тест в ссылке.
Подскажите пожалуйста, или хотя бы дайте ссылку с аналогичным примером.

Спасибо.
С уважением, Александр

Comment: У datapicker-ра есть события на все случаи жизни, и через установку своих обработчиков на них можно сделать что угодно.

Comment: datapicker можно привязать к чему угодно. input просто чаще других элементов используется.

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даже не перечитывая мануалы, можно сделать следующим образом:

```
var dateLink = $('#my_date'); // ваша ссылка

dateLink.on('click', function(){
    $('<input type="text" id="hidden_datepicker" />')
        .insertAfter(this)
        .css({
            border: 'none',
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        })
        .datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                dateLink.text('Выбрана дата: ' + dateText);
                $(this).remove();
            }
        }).datepicker('show');
});
```

Работу скрипта, [можно посмотреть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/BCFPn/7/).

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо!!!

Comment: @Александр Колпаков, плиззз ))